# Removing files using python from a server using FTP

Tags: python, server, ftp, ftplib

I’m having a hard time with this simple script. It’s giving me an error of file or directory not found but the file is there. Script below I’ve masked user and pass plus FTP site

Here is my script

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp.domain.ca')
pas = str('PASSWORD')
ftp.login(user = 'user', passwd=pas)
ftp.cwd('/public_html/')

filepaths = open('errorstest.csv', 'rb')

for j in filepaths:
    print(j)
    ftp.delete(str(j))
ftp.quit()
```

The funny thing tho is if I slight change the script to have ftp.delete() it finds the file and deletes it. So modified to be like this:

```
from ftplib import FTP


ftp = FTP('ftp.domain.ca')
pas = str('PASSWORD')
ftp.login(user = 'user', passwd=pas)
ftp.cwd('/public_html/')
ftp.delete(<file path>)
ftp.quit()
```

I’m trying to read this from a csv file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show us the `ftp.retrlines('LIST')` and the `errorstest.csv` file content ?

Comment: Thanks I’ve added below

Comment: And please paste the exact error that you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you have showed seems to be fine. But could you try this?

```py
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP(host)
ftp.login(username, password)
ftp.cwd('/public_html/')
print(ftp.pwd())
print(ftp.nlst())
with open('errorstest.csv') as file:
    for line in file:   
        if line.strip():
            ftp.delete(line.strip())

print(ftp.nlst())
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but help me understand what I did wrong vs your solution?

Comment: I asked you for the `exact` `error` that you got, while running. But i presume, the error you saw was because of the `newline` in the `errorstest.csv`, and since you didn't check for `empt` lines, like i did, it tried to `delete` the `empty` line from the `ftp` path, and it failed. You can see, i made a check `if line.strip():` in my code, which will check for `empty` lines. Your script still may have been working, it just give the error, when tried to `delete` the `new line`. I think, that is what you were seeing :)